# Magento 2.3.5 PWA implement tab component

Tags: magento2.3, tabs, pwa, component, react

I am interested to learn more about how to implement the Tabs found here: `https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/pagebuilder/components/tabs/`

One can use react bootstrap tab ref: `https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/`

But I'm interested in the build in Tab!

I'm just a bit confused as to how/what file to import and how to start using it ?

Thanks

Comment: hmmm interesting! What's the downvote for? care to share you option? if you don't have any info stop clicking button for the sake of it!

Answer (score 0):

This is How I've implemented it!

```
...
import Tabs from '@magento/pagebuilder/lib/ContentTypes/Tabs';
...

   ... 
   const tabProps = {
            tabNavigationAlignment: 'right',
            minHeight: '300px',
            defaultIndex: 0,
            headers: ['Tab 1'],
            border: 'solid',
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: '10px',
            borderRadius: '5px',
            marginTop: '10px',
            marginRight: '10px',
            marginBottom: '10px',
            marginLeft: '10px',
            paddingTop: '10px',
            paddingRight: '10px',
            paddingBottom: '10px',
            paddingLeft: '10px',
            cssClasses: ['test-class']
        };
    
    <Tabs {...tabProps}>
              <div>Tab 1 content</div>
           </Tabs>
    ...
```

[image]